# tikzpicture negative gamma function

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, graphs

[image]I'm trying to plot the following graph in tikzpicture:

[image]

However, I have a hard time defining the function properly, as my MWE currently is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
            gamma(\x)= 0.25*\x*\x*exp(-0.5*\x);
    }
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:13, samples=200,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$\tau$, ylabel=$V(\tau)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  xtick={4}, 
  xticklabel={$\tau^{\ast}$},
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  %grid = major,    
  xmin=0, ymin=0,
]
\addplot [very thick,cyan] {gamma(x)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated! 
Many thanks!

Comment: Remove the `clip=false` and `ymin=0` options, and plot `{-gamma(x)}` instead of `{gamma(x)}`, and you should get the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code and result is mainly from Jake's comment (no CW answer as no wiki intended and possible points I could then put via bounty to Jake's great answers)

- remove `clip=false`
- remove `ymin=0`
- plot the negative function: `\addplot [very thick,cyan] {-gamma(x)};`

And then, for a top x axis

- add `axis x line = top` as axis option

So, you will get:

[image: Output Gamma function]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
            gamma(\x)= 0.25*\x*\x*exp(-0.5*\x);
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:13, samples=200,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$\tau$, ylabel=$V(\tau)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  xtick={4}, 
  xticklabel={$\tau^{\ast}$},
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false,
  axis x line = top,
  xmin=0,
]
\addplot [very thick,cyan] {-gamma(x)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```